# Django- How to get last uploaded file into template?

Tags: django

I am making a site where users can upload sound files. They can see the list of user-uploaded sound files and play them.

This much works. I have made a for loop of the object list with audio elements.

However, additionally, I also want to be able to place only the most recently added sound file on its own at the bottom of the template so that it can be dealt with separately (i.e. I want to put it in an audio element separate from those in the list and also be able to access it on its own in the template to process it using WebAudio API).

I know I need to use a filter and I keep reading that Model.objects.latest(‘field’) should do the job (I assume in views.py) but I am doing something very wrong as whatever I put in my view and my template creates errors. I am using class-based views and Django version 3.1.7

If anyone can show me with what I need to put into my model, my view, and my template so that I can get just the last added sound file into my template from the object list. I would be very grateful.

My model looks like this:

```
class SoundFile(models.Model):
    sound_file = models.FileField()  
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('download-file')
```

My views look like this:

```
class SoundUploadView(generic.CreateView):

   model = SoundFile
   fields = ['sound_file']
   template_name = 'upload.html'

class SoundDownloadView(generic.ListView):

    model = SoundFile
    fields = ['sound_file']
    template_name = 'download.html'
```

My templates look like this:

Upload.html

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
<form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.media }}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Download.html

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <div class="container">
    {% for document in object_list %}
    <p> {{ document.sound_file.name }} </p>
    <p> Created on: {{ document.created_on}} </p>
    <p> Last modified: {{ document.last_modified}} </p>    

        <audio controls id="player"><source src="{{ document.sound_file.url }}"></audio>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  
  <div>  
    <a class="button" href="../upload"> Upload your version</a>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Thank you!

Traceback:
If I try to apply the filter in the view by adding the following:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return SoundFile.objects.last()
```

So that the whole view is:

```
class SoundDownloadView(generic.ListView):

    model = SoundFile
    fields = ['sound_file']
    template_name = 'download.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return SoundFile.objects.last()
```

I get an error with the following traceback:

```
Django Version:     3.1.7
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

'SoundFile' object is not iterable

Exception Location:     /Users/cameronharris/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py, line 167, in render
Python Executable:  /Users/cameronharris/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.9.2
Python Path:    

['/Users/cameronharris/django_test/Headroom',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/cameronharris/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing only a single `SoundFile` object to the template, then you are trying to iterate that *single* object in a for-loop, that's why you are getting a `'SoundFile' object is not iterable` error.

the [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) is used when you have to display a list of objects. Here, in your case, you have only one object to represent, So it is highly recommended to use a [Detilview](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview).

But If you still want to use [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview), then try this

```
<!-- removed the loop, change context name to object_list -->
<p> {{ object_list.sound_file.name }} </p>
<p> Created on: {{ object_list.created_on}} </p>
<p> Last modified: {{ object_list.last_modified}} </p>    
<audio controls id="player"><source src="{{ document.sound_file.url }}"></audio>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works! The only thing I needed to change from your answer was in the <audio> element: I also needed to change document to object_list in the same way you did for the <p> elements. I should have thought about the fact Detailview is the appropriate view to use and will work with that going forward but I can confirm your answer does work with my current ListView. Thanks again, Cameron