# how to get the last file uploaded to templates

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-templates, django-file-upload

i want to get the last file i was upload and it will be played in templates. but what i make it, every file i was upload, it can be played (so there’s so many audio player). what i want is just show 1 audio player with the last audio i was upload it. i was trying with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66672938/django-how-to-get-last-uploaded-file-into-template) but it's not work on me.

here's my html:

```
     <audio controls="controls">
            <source src="/media/mp3/{{last_audio.audio}}" type="audio/mpeg">
     </audio>
```

views.py:

```
def homepage(request):
    form = AudioForm()
    last_audio = Audio_store.objects.last()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AudioForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            audio = form.cleaned_data.get("audio")
            print(audio)
            context={'form':form, 'last_audio':audio}
        return render(request, 'homepage.html', context)

    context={'form':form, 'last_audio':last_audio}
    return render(request, "homepage.html", context=context)
```

it's not error again but now the audio controls not appear, but the audio can be selected the last

Answer (score 0):

view

```
def homepage(request):
    form = AudioForm()
    last_audio = Audio_store.objects.last()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AudioForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            audio = form.cleaned_data.get("audio")
        return render(request, home.html, {'last_audio':audio})

    context={'form':form, 'last_audio':last_audio}
    print(audio)
    return render(request, "homepage.html", context=context)
```

html

```
 <audio controls="controls">
        <source src="/media/mp3/{{last_audio.audio}}" type="audio/mpeg">
 </audio>
```

Comment: still it's get all song from local

Comment: I updated the answer. You need to delete your for loop in the HTML file.  Don't forget to change all() to last()

Comment: yes, i was already delete the loop. now it's have error message : TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'function'

Comment: This error is not related to my solution. Where is the error in views?

Comment: i updated add pictures the error

Comment: Can you update your changed files

Comment: already updated and now the problem is my audio controls not appear

Comment: Do you have this project on Github if so then send here the repo link

Comment: im sorry, i dont have github. so i can upload it to gdrive. here's the link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XXfCltDkPf3Qr5nKzYTxe1vPXgpeI687?usp=sharing

Comment: could you open it?

Comment: yes, I did.  I will solve your problem as soon as possible

Comment: thank you! do you already done?